# Automatic Key Strokes

Tags: windows-10, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a custom software where there is no automatic delete button (to delete a record). I need to delete literally 100's of lines to remove custom pricing. Right now, I can delete lines through the file `menu → delete`. I can make it slightly shorter by typing <kbd>Alt + F + D</kbd> (<kbd>alt</kbd> `→ File → Delete)` but typing that out hundreds of times is frustrating.

Is there a way to make automatic keystrokes with my keyboard so I can press one letter or key and it automatically logs <kbd>Alt + F + D</kbd>?

Could this be done with a macro, or batch file?

This isn't a Microsoft program so any typical shortcut would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/). It's free, open source software and can likely do what you need.

Particularly, it runs background scripts that monitor key presses and does things in response to certain keys based on those scripts. For instance, if you wanted to send a literal <kbd>Alt + F + D</kbd>, you could try e.g.:

```
a::Send !fd
```

You would place this in an `.ahk` script file, which AutoHotKey would run in the background. The result would be that every time you pressed the `a` key (or whichever key you specified), <kbd>Alt + F + D</kbd> should be triggered.

Comment: Interesting - thank you. However I am not 100% certain how to get that script started. Would the AutoHotKey be a download and I define the trigger letter and key stroke result (Alt + F + D)

Comment: Your welcome. =) Yes, you have it exactly. You would first [get a copy of AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/download/) and place it on the PC where you wished to used the script. AutoHotkey has the ability to either be installed normally or run in a portable, self-contained way (so you could simply place its files in a folder on your desktop, for instance). You would then create a new text file with a line similar to what I show in my answer (which defines the example trigger letter `a` and the keystroke result Alt [!] + F + D). But yes, this definition is up to you.

Comment: You would then run that script with AutoHotKey. If you installed AutoHotKey, `.ahk` scripts are registered automatically (so you you could double-click e.g. `myscript.ahk` to run it). Otherwise, scripts can run from the command line with e.g. `C:\path\to\AutoHotkeyA32.exe C:\path\to\myscript.ahk`.  This second option allows them to be placed in batch files or used as the target of new shortcuts. As a small note, the `.ahk` extension isn't required if you use the script from the command line (vs. double-clicking).

Comment: Whenever a script is run, a small icon is created in the Windows notification area (where your clock lives) which allows you to pause or exit the script. This can be handy if you need to use your trigger key again for its intended use. =P

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked and saved me so so much time!

Comment: You're welcome. I am sincerely glad you got things taken care of easier. =)